# dlopen on a library that requires other libraries

Tags: c, dynamic-linking

Looking for help regarding the error `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when using `dlopen()` on a shared library that requires other shared libraries.

I can't find anything on how to properly handle this and link the other required shared libraries.

I appreciate any help!

```
void *handle;
char *error;

handle = dlopen("lib/mylib.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (!handle) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

dlerror();
```

Comment: Do you know what other shared libraries are required? Where are they? Setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to their location is a common way of telling where to find other dependencies.

Comment: @yano All the needed libraries are in the same lib directory as the library I'm trying to call functions from. I just tried setting the env variable of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which still returns the same error.

Comment: If you run the program under `strace`, it will show what files were probed for in what directories and what the results were. That's the best way to figure this out. Statically, you can run `ldd` and/or `readelf` on the `.so` files to see what shared libraries they want. My guess is that if all `.so` files are in the subdir `lib`, that's the issue. Try: `cd lib ; ./program` (changing the `dlopen` to just `"mylib.so"`) Or, `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib`

Comment: You're sure? You've done `ldd myExec` and `ldd mylib.so` and you recognize everything and accounted for their locations? If the `mylib.so` dependencies have their own dependencies, you can go down a rabbit hole pretty quickly. Using `strace` sounds like a good idea, never tried that before.

Comment: `export tLD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib` does work! Also using strace is helpful so I'll keep that in mind for the future, thank you guys so much